# Lubuntu 18.04, rsync gives me ‘sh: rsync: command not found’ rsync version 3.1.2 is installed

Tags: ssh, lubuntu, rsync

I am trying to rsync the root folder of an iPhone over ssh into a folder at `/home/Ryan/Downloads/iphone`

```
$ rsync-e ssh root@192.168.0.74:/ /home/Ryan/Downloads/iphone
```

I then enter the password when printed and then receive this:

```
sh: rsync: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [reciever]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(235) [reciever=3.1.2]
```

I know that this is the correct IP and name for the device because I can use ssh by itself and use `dir` to show the folders within that I want to copy.

Answer (score 1):

The remote client has not rsync installed which generates the `sh: rsync: command not found` error.

Same question was asked here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1432412/rsync-installed-but-still-getting-an-error-command-not-found/1432433

An alternative would be to mount data from the remote on your local via NFS, SMB, SSHFS, ... There is an example here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204530/copy-from-remote-server-which-doesnt-have-rsync